# Why can't I add a keyword protected, private or public before class Todo?

Tags: android

The HttpHelper.java incude the two class *HttpHelper* and *Todo*, the code works well.

If I add a keyword before class Todo, such as

```
private   class Todo{}
public    class Todo{}
protected class Todo{}
```

the system will report error, why ?

**HttpHelper.java**

```
public class HttpHelper {


}

class Todo{
}
```

Comment: It has to be a nested class if you want to do that.

Comment: Basically, when you compile the HttpHelper file, it can't create two classes that are at the same "top level" of the file

Comment: Thanks! isn't the class Todo{} top level  ?

Comment: It is, which is why it won't work when you add the modifier

Comment: A private class would be a class you could only access from within the same class it's in. But it's not in another class, so that makes no sense.

Comment: I know that I can use the class Todo{} within the public class HttpHelper {}, can I use  the class Todo{} in other class?

Answer (score 0):

because the key word 'protected' can only be used before a inner class 
as this

```
class A{
     protected class B{

    }
}
```